# My program runs out of memory (Stack overflow) 9 out of 10 times. But where is the issue in my algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, performance, actionscript, stack-overflow

I've made the following program to simulate the classic card game "War". But when I try to run it, it experiences stack overflow. Why? I thought my algorithm was as effective as it could be. Another weird thing that happens is that 1 out of 10 times the program will finish, returning a VERY low vale for the round count (around 26). The code is as follows:

Firstly, I have a class named Card.

```
package  {

    public class Card {
            public var cardName:String;
            public var suit:String;
            public var number:int;
        public function Card() {

        }

    }

}
```

Then I have the following code:

```
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

var cardDeck:Array = new Array();
var suits:Array = new Array();
suits = ["Hearts", "Clubs", "Spades", "Diamonds"];

for each (var suit in suits)
    {
        for (var a = 1; a <= 13; a++)
            {
                var card:Card = new Card();
                card.cardName = suit + a;
                card.number = a;
                card.suit = suit;
                cardDeck.push(card);
            }
    }

var shuffledCardDeck:Array = new Array();
var randomPos:int = 0;
for (var b = 0; b < 52; b++) {
    randomPos = Math.random()*cardDeck.length;
    shuffledCardDeck[b] = cardDeck[randomPos];
    cardDeck.splice(randomPos, 1);
}

var handOne:Array = new Array();
var handTwo:Array = new Array();

for (var c = 0; c < 26; c++) {
    handOne.push(shuffledCardDeck[c]);
}

for (var d = 26; d < 52; d++) {
    handTwo.push(shuffledCardDeck[d]);
}

var roundCount:int;

round();

function round() {
    roundCount+=1;

    var cardOne:Card = handOne[0];
    var cardTwo:Card = handTwo[0];

    if (cardOne.number < cardTwo.number) {
        // Player two wins
        handTwo.push(cardOne);
        handOne.splice(0, 1);
    } else if (cardOne.number > cardTwo.number) {
        // Player one wins
        handOne.push(cardTwo);
        handTwo.splice(0, 1);
    } else {
        // Draw
        handOne.splice(0,1)
        handOne.push(cardOne);
        handTwo.splice(0,1)
        handTwo.push(cardTwo);
    }
    if (handOne.length == 0 || handTwo.length == 0) {
         trace("Good game")
    } else {
        round();
    }
}
trace(roundCount);
```

Comment: It's actionscript. I have already added the actionscript tag.

Comment: Function round is recursive. Check that it always finishes.

Comment: I'm not too experienced. How would I do that? Doesn't it only run ones when it's called. And shouldn't it stop being called after one of the hands reaches 0 cards?

Comment: Add some trace statements above "if (handOne.length == 0 || handTwo.length == 0) {" and/or inside the else statement that calls round()

Comment: You call it once, but it calls itself again and again (last `else` branch), causing stack overflow.You have to recheck logic and ensure that stop condition is fulfilled ever.

Comment: @MBo Yeah, but my thinking is that the final `if` statement should stop the game when one hand has 0 cards. And then the `else` statement wont happen, which means that the function will stopped being called. Am I wrong?

Comment: @RobertN I tried it now, and nothing out of the usual. The rare times it ends, is when one hand actually reaches 0. But most of the times, I run out of memory first. But that makes no sense. I think the average "War" game should last about 400 hands. But the games here are lasting several thousands.

Comment: If you're expecting hundreds of levels of recursion even in an ordinary case, I think you would be better off with a non-recursive algorithm (e.g., `while (round()); // keep playing until someone wins`). And try adding a few sanity checks to your code (e.g., the total number of cards in both hands should always be 52).

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Okay! I'll try that out. But shouldn't it still be possible to do it my way?

Comment: @Smebbs Yes, probably. But unless you can calculate an exact worst-case figure for the maximum recursion level in this game, you will always run the risk of crashing unexpectedly.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage But why would `while` be a better solution then? Wouldn't the `while` expression run out of memory if the condition never/rarely becomes true. Can the `while` expression handle thousands of repetitions if my way of solving it can't? Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you win a round, do you play the next round with the same card? Because that's what's happening

Comment: Also, depending on what your doing, the stack is limited to around 4000-5000 (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192839/is-the-stack-limit-of-5287-in-as3-variable-or-predefined) - so either move it to a while, or do it over multiple frames (use `onEnterFrame`)

Comment: @divillysausages Wait, how come the same card is being used the next round? That is probably the error. Isn't the variables `cardOne` and `cardTwo` being changed every round? Edit: Aah, I think I saw it. The winning hand keeps their card. That's wrong. Thank you for the help!

Comment: It looks to me like if a hand has a card with number=1 it can never lose it. So as long as each hand has at least one card with number=1, the game will never finish.

Answer (score 0):

Flash runtime’s maximum recursion limit is default 1000, but can be set via the compiler argument default-script-limits. Instead of just recursion, call the function in an interval to prevent such stack overflow. It will be helpful even when you decide to show visually the process to the gamers.

```
setTimeout(round,50); //in place of round();
```

Source: http://www.designswan.com/archives/as3-recursive-functions-vs-loop-functions.html